# How to proceed with Vandermonde's formula when it's multipled with iterating variable?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

I was solving one problem where I am stuck in the middle...
Plz kindly suggest some ways to proceed further..
So the problem is:

The value of

$$\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{100}{{k}\choose{i}}{{m-k}\choose{100-i}}\frac{k-i}{m-100}}{{m}\choose{100}}$$

where :

$m-k > 100$,

$k > 100$ 
equals ?

1. $k$/$m$
2. $m$/$k$
3. $k$/$m^2$
4. $m$/$k$

So to solve this what I did:

I separated the $k-i$ term as $k$ and $-i$ along with other factors and then the term having $k$ was a Vandermondes property but what about the term with $i$??

My problem is how to proceed in those cases where Vandermondes property is multiplied by $i$...?

I wrote the given term as:

$$\frac{\sum{{k}\choose{i}}{{m-k}\choose{100-i}}\frac{k}{m-100}}{{m}\choose{100}}-\frac{\sum{{k}\choose{i}}{{m-k}\choose{100-i}}\frac{i}{m-100}}{{m}\choose{100}}
$$

Now here the first term is succinctly Vandermondes formula multiplied with $k$, which is a constant..
So I applied the property and got this:

$$\frac{{{m}\choose{100}}\frac{k}{m-100}}{{m}\choose{100}}
-\frac{\sum{{k}\choose{i}}{{m-k}\choose{100-i}}\frac{i}{m-100}}{{m}\choose{100}}
$$

Now how to proceed with the second term..
There "i" is multiplied to Vandermondes property ..!!
How to simplify in such cases..??
(Plz suggest some good articles / links also for further read on the approaches if possible.)

P.S.

Vandermondes Formula:

$${n+m \choose k} = \sum_{j=0}^{k}{n \choose j}{m \choose k-j}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $i<k$ we have $(k-i)\binom{k}{i}=\frac{k!}{i!(k-i-1)!}=\color{blue}{k}\binom{k-1}{i}$. Thus, denoting $s=100$, your value is $$\binom{m}{s}^{-1}\frac{k}{m-s}\sum_{i=0}^{s}\binom{k-1}{i}\binom{m-k}{s-i}=\binom{m}{s}^{-1}\frac{k}{m-s}\binom{m-1}{s}=\frac{k}{m}.$$

Comment: First of all very sorry I cant respond to the answer given by you!!..I had my online exams lined up one after another so was packed..

Comment: You answer is excellent made my all concepts clear..!!! I can't thank you much..really appreciate your efforts..

Comment: I was messing around with big concepts and missed upon the very basics..thanks again

Comment: @PiyushSawarkar: Oh, feel free. Personally I dislike "choice questions", but this one clearly displays your efforts. By the way, you would succeed if you noted a similarly reasoned identity $i\binom{k}{i}=k\binom{k-1}{i-1}$. [But it would be longer.]

Comment: Oh yes! Even by that logic I got answer ...but yes it was too long...thanks :-)